# JS code creating issue in Django project ("introduce local variable")

Tags: javascript, django, visual-studio-code, pycharm, frontend

I am running in a ridiculous problem with django. the same code it works here and in VScode (only these 3 files). but when i implement the sets of codes in the django project in pycharm or vscode, the js code, does not respond in a right right, it shows there that i have to "introduce local variable. What is wrong? :(

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".carousel").carousel();
});
```

```css
.carousel {
  height: 250px;
  perspective:175px;
}
.carousel .carousel-item {
  width: 250px;
}
.carousel .carousel-item img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
.carousel .carousel-item h2 {
  margin: -5px 0 0;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Main/static/blog/imageslider.css" />
      <script src="/Main/static/functionality/imageslider.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="carousel">
      <a class="carousel-item" href="#"
        ><img src="/Main/static/pics/photo-1454942901704-3c44c11b2ad1.jpg" alt="">
        <h2>3D CAROUSEL</h2>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-item" href="#"
        ><img src="/Main/static/pics/photo-1454942901704-3c44c11b2ad1.jpg" alt="" />
        <h2>3D CAROUSEL</h2>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-item" href="#"
        ><img src="/Main/static/pics/photo-1454942901704-3c44c11b2ad1.jpg" alt=""/>
        <h2>3D CAROUSEL</h2>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-item" href="#"
        ><img
          src="/Main/static/pics/photo-1454942901704-3c44c11b2ad1.jpg"
         alt=""/>
        <h2>3D CAROUSEL</h2>
      </a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can always _edit_ your question; you don't need to remove it and ask it again.

Comment: Alright, thank you. Won't happen again! Sorry!

Comment: I think the the problem is that your `css` and `js` files are not loading in django. Did you setup static files in the `settings.py`? if so, show us your configuration.

Comment: @PedramParsian, yeah i have steup the static file in the settings.py, tho i have 2 different static folders, in different places, do you think that, that may be the issue, and as for the configuration, how i am supposed t show it to you i didnt really get that :/.